# Run replace script in Google App Maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I would like to add a server script that replaces special characters when a textbox is filled. The info for the "onValueEdit" routine states:
*This script will run on the client whenever the value of this widget is edited by the user. The widget can be referenced using parameter widget and the new value of the widget is stored in newValue. Unlike onValueChange(), this runs only when a user changes the value of the widget; it won't run in response to bindings or when the value is set programmatically.*

Therefore I have built the following server script that should take the text from the textbox, overwrite the special characters and replace the text in the textbox. But when I add the script to "onValueEdit" event, Google App Maker returns "function is undefined".

```javascript
function cleanup(input, output) {
  if (input !== null) {
    output = input.trim();
    output = output.replace('ß','ss');
    output = output.replace('ä','ae');
    output = output.replace('ö','oe');
    output = output.replace('ü','ue');
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to give a lot more info to get useful help. On a different note, why is `output` an argument for your function, and then also its return value? Your function does not use the given `output` argument at all.

Comment: As with your other question - is this script run on the client or on the server? Server functions can be called from the client with `google.script.run.<function name>` as explained in App Maker documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to make this changes only on client side the ritgh way to do it will be adding this code to the `onValueEdit` event handler:

```javascript
// onValueEdit input's event handler
if (newValue !== null) {
  output = newValue.trim();

  output = output.replace('ß','ss');
  ...

  widget.value = output;
}
```

If you need to securely enforce this override prior to persisting to database, then you need to go with [Model Events](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events):

```javascript
// onBeforeCreate and onBeforeSave events
if (record.FieldToChange !== null) {
  record.FieldToChange = record.FieldToChange.trim();
  record.FieldToChange = record.FieldToChange.replace('ß','ss');
  ...
}
```

With this approach you don't need any client code since all changes made on server should automatically sync back to client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.